# TypeOrm No metadata for User was found. Only in production

Tags: node.js, express, typeorm

I have a repository [github](https://github.com/quanghieple/hr-server/tree/stag2)

everything work fine when I start production in local by following command (you can start app with branch `stag2`)

```
npm start build
cd ./dist && npm start
```

but when I deploy into Heroku, I got an error when load entity User successful

```
{"0":"No metadata for \"User\" was found.","level":"error","message":"[api:middlewares/ErrorHandlerMiddleware] EntityMetadataNotFound"}
```

You can try post request to

#local

```
Post localhost:9000/api/login
{
 data: {username: "admin", password: "admin@hr"}
}
```

#Heroku

```
Post https://hrsol.herokuapp.com/api/login
{
 data: {username: "admin", password: "admin@hr"}
}
```

TypeOrm config can find in `.env` and `src/env.ts`

Anyone know how to fix it? Thank you

Comment: Provide your `ormconfig` part.

Answer (score 0):

This means that your `User` model has *not* been registered with TypeORM. That's all there is to it.

Make sure that you are declaring this in your `TypeOrmModule.forRoot({ entities: [ User ] })` call or using a proper path(s) and/or glob(s) to import *.js from the filesystem.

If you're still stuck please pluck out the relevant pieces of code from your github repository (I tried, it's a navigation nightmare).